# UNIX script to LPAD update query in cat file

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, bash, unix, microsoft-word

I want script which will open the text file data and write update query to those file and save in SQL file which will get executed through cron. I have prepared command but its writing the update query in RPAD Below given is the sample data & command :

```
text file data : cat file.txt
123456789
234567891
345678912
456789123
```

Command:

> cat file.txt | sed 's/$/update table set field where file_number="file.txt"/'> file1.sql

Current OUTPUT :

```
123456789update table set field where file_number=
234567891update table set field where file_number=
345678912update table set field where file_number=
456789123update table set field where file_number=
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
update table set field where file_number='123456789';
update table set field where file_number='234567891';
update table set field where file_number='345678912';
update table set field where file_number='456789123';
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more elegant approaches (however, any of those come to my mind right now), so let's stick to `sed`.

- **Why isn't you command working as you expect it?**

  `$` matches the *end of line*, that's why your `update table ...` string gets placed at the end of each line.
- **How to improve?**

  1. You don't need `cat`; `sed` takes a file as an argument, too.
  2. Define the whole line as a matching pattern (`.*` matches everything, enclose it in escaped brackets to reference it: `\(.*\)`
  3. Use the sql command string as a replacement and place the reference mark `\1` where appropriate:

     ```
     sed "s|\(.*\)|update table set field where file_number=\'\1\';|" file.txt > file.sql
     ```

     producing

     ```
     update table set field where file_number='123456789';
     update table set field where file_number='234567891';
     update table set field where file_number='345678912';
     update table set field where file_number='456789123';
     ```